# Laravel Eloquent rollback does not work, for queries separated by PHP functions

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I separate the model queries on a trait class, because I hate to read a long block of codes with the model queries, and because I find it convenient if I reused the same function. But I found a problem once an error occur.

I was trying to run rollback function from eloquent once an error occur but, unfortunately, rollback wont work as I am expecting.

Am I doing it wrong? 
Are there any other ways to implement this?

```
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();


        // UserDetails
        $userdetailsID = $this->saveUserDetails($request,$userData->id);

        if($userdetailsID){
            $result = $this->saveUser(
                $request,
                $this->getHashValue($request->password),
                $userdetailsID,
                $userData->id,
                $this->cleanTobeSafeAsDirectory(crypt(($userdetailsID.$userData->companyid), 'rl'))
                );

            if($result){
                $updalodResult = $this->uploadThisImage( $request , 'images/uploads/users/'.$userdetailsID.'/icon/', '_'.$this->getHashValue($userdetailsID),'userImageAvatar');
                if($updalodResult['success']){
                    $resul = $this->getThisUserDetials($userdetailsID);
                    $resul->photo_name = $updalodResult['filename'];
                    $resul->save();

                    $imageFilePath = 'images/uploads/users/'.$userdetailsID.'/icon/'.$updalodResult['filename'];
                    $this->cropImageJpegOnly($imageFilePath,$request->img_x,$request->img_y,$request->img_w,$request->img_h,$request->img_width,$request->img_height);
                }
                DB::commit();
                return $this->returnAsAppSuccess('User information added.');
            }
            DB::rollBack();
            return $this->returnAsAppError('Failed to user security details.' );
        }


        DB::rollBack();
        return $this->returnAsAppError('Failed to user security details.' );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return $this->returnAsAppError('Failed to insert User information.');
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you are calling `DB::rollBack();` to many times, you only need to call it if another query has already completed, such as "Insert in table A" then "Insert in table B fail" you call rollback to undo the successful insert in table "A", usually this is because the two entries are related and missing one will leave the other fragmented, or orphaned.

Comment: Also in general ( not sure of how Laravel does it ) roll backs, wont remove files that were uploaded, unless they are stored solely in the DB, it will undo the record assuming its InnoDB engine type, MyISAM does not support transactions, and having a MyISAM table in the mix can silently commit your transactions.