# Laravel Eloquent Call to a member function getConnection() on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Why do I get this error? The rest of my queries work except this

```
    $clients = DB::select(DB::raw('
        SELECT clients.*,users2.* 
        from clients 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                users.id,
                users.userdetailsid,
                usermoredetails.address,
                usermoredetails.progbackgroundimage,
                usermoredetails.photo_name,
                usermoredetails.fname,
                usermoredetails.lname,
                usermoredetails.mname,
                usermoredetails.mobilenumber,
                usermoredetails.email,
                usermoredetails.gender,
                usermoredetails.civilstatus,
                usermoredetails.addedby
            FROM users
            INNER JOIN usermoredetails ON usermoredetails.id = users.userdetailsid 
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS users2 on users2.id = clients.userid
        where clients.active = 1'));
```

But if run the query through phpmyadmin, it works fine. Where did it went wrong?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: This piece of code does not contain your error, where is `getConnection` called .  The error tells you that is called on a "non-Object" meaning you could do `$foo = 'foo'; $foo::getConnection()` now we are calling it on a string, a Non object. (more likely in my example is $foo = null)

Comment: Do any queries work? or just this one fails.  I don't use Laravel by the way but I professionally program PHP for 6+ years.

Comment: show your database config, your env config of db

Comment: Thanks @ArtisticPhoenix. Anyway, I manage to solve this problem earlier by creating a new instance of Manager and set it to global. It seems laravel does not set it globally by default, that is why this method wont work.

Comment: The bad thing is that I added the code on my AuthenticationMiddleware which I believe it is not a good practice. because I am afraid to mess with the laravel code. To be honest I dont know how set the default connection set by laravel to global.

Comment: I would not set it to global, the correct way would be to create a new instance of it, pass in by dependency injection, or if it's a singleton then do something like `DB::getInstance()` as I said I don't know about laravel but if it has a getInstance method then you can assume it's a singleton.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: AS a side note, I would add `usermoredetails.userid` as a foreign key, it seems you have a foreign key in users for that table, That would imply that Many Users can use the same details,  The other way, put user_id in the details, is 1 User can have many details.  Likely what you have in reality is a One to One, but by putting userid in that table instead you can eliminate a join in your above sql, and likely the sub-query.  If that makes sense. Then you could join, clients directly to the details table by userid....  But I only have one query to go by.

Comment: I can give you a more detailed example of the above if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: I think the laravel eloquent connection is in singleton as it used by Models except for the Capsule/Manager I gues. It seam Capsule/Manager does'nt have instance yet or was'nt connected to its default connection. Maybe that is the reason why DB::getInstance() will return Null.

Comment: I'll try to reconsider adding a foreign key on Client from UsermoreDetails to prevent this long string of query. Actually i'll added a foreign key to Client before and I did remove it later since client is still a User too. But thanks @ArtisticPhoenix i think I should change that. Thanks

Comment: Anyway @ArtisticPhoenix can I ask you an idea to this problem I posted? I believe you have far experience than me when it comes to php and eloquent. Hope you could help. Thanks.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422221/laravel-eloquent-rollback-does-not-work-for-queries-separated-by-php-functions

Comment: I never Used Laravel or Eloquent, but I have done MySql for like 6+ years.